# How to SingleChildScrollView scroll to TextField focus in dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem when show an alert dialog. My AlertDialog too tall (many TextFields). When I click any below TextFields, keyboard makes dialog short and SingleChildScrollView (I wrap my content in it) does not scroll to the TextField which has focus. However, when I type a character on that textfield, SingleChildScrollView works fine, scrolls to that TextField automatically. So, how do SingleChildScrollView scrolls to a TextField when user click in the first time (has focus).
p/s: I tried add a listener into FocusNode, but it does not work.

For example: I will click 'Fullname' field (picture 1) and the keyboard makes dialog short and I can not see the 'Fullname' field (picture 2). When I type a character, the scrollview scroll to that correctly (picture 3).
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        'Dialog Title',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text('Cancel'.toUpperCase()),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text('OK'.toUpperCase()),
        ),
      ],
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              focusNode: _nodePhone,
              maxLength: 10,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone number',
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nodeEmail);
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              focusNode: _nodeEmail,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nodeFullname);
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              focusNode: _nodeFullname,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Fullname',
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nodePassword);
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              focusNode: _nodePassword,
              obscureText: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Not yet, bro. But my team decided to choose to create a separate screen for it, we do not use dialog for this case anymore, because the content is too much and too long.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, I manage to solve it by give a controller to SingleChildScrollView then when onTap on TextField. Await for few millisecond for dialog to collapse then scroll to the end of dialog

Here is some sample code

```
//declare first
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

//your field code
SingleChildScrollView(
    // give a controller
    controller: _scrollController,
    child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: < Widget > [
            TextField(
                focusNode: _nodePhone,
                maxLength: 10,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Phone number',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onEditingComplete: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nodeEmail);
                },
            ),
            //suppose this is your very last textfield
            TextField(
                focusNode: _nodeEmail,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onEditingComplete: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nodeFullname);
                },
                onTap: () {
                    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                        _scrollController.animateTo(
                            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                            curve: Curves.ease);
                    });
                },
            ),
        ]
    )
);
```

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to say thank you, but currently, scroll onTap working fine without your code, you can try. This problem happened when you focus a field, and then click 'Next' button on keyboard to move next field.